# Recaman sequence in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to create Recaman's sequence using recursion in python, and I am having difficulty doing so.

I understand how Recaman's sequence works. In my case, given rec(n), every nth term is equal to the previous term minus n if the value has not previously appeared in the sequence and would be equal to the previous term minus n otherwise.

My main issue with this problem would be figuring out how to somehow 'save' each rec(n) to check if it has previously appeared, and then compare the existing n to that value.

My code so far does not show much, but I believe I do have to add a parameter and use a wrapper function/accumulative recursion to get this to work.

This is my current code, it definitely does not work but I am trying to store values in a list.

```py
def rec(n):
  list = []
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  elif rec(n-1) - n in list:
    list.append(rec(n-1) - n)
    return rec(n-1) - n
  else:
    list.append(rec(n-1) + n)
    return rec(n-1) + n
```

Comment: This gives don't detailed solutions https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recamans-sequence/

Comment: Use a `set` as your base, instead of a list (searching `set` is faster than searching `list`), and pass a set as a parameter in the recursive function instead of initializing it inside the function. Each iteration, add the new value to the set.

Comment: Despite the recursive definition, it's much easier to just compute the values of the function iteratively. This is a simple application of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: I haven't actually learned set() yet so I'm not sure if it's a function I'm allowed to use. Would list do the trick though?

Comment: Yeah, you should be fine with `list`. The problem lies in initializing the `list` inside the recursive function as Green Cloak Guy told you. Everytime you call `rec(n)` you will be creating a new empty list. What you want is to have the list as an argument to keep the record of the elements already stored. You could define a new function `rec_i(n,list)` and call it inside `rec(n)` like `rec_i(n,[])`.

Comment: If I were to make such a function, do you mind giving me hints on where I would call it in my existing code?

Comment: Yeah of course! It should be something like:
`def rec_i(n,list):` In this function you implement the program as you were doing in `rec(n)`, but instead of creating a new empty list, you append the item to the list sent as parameter and then use it back in the return statement (`return rec_i(n-1,list)`). After implementing the whole algorithm in rec_i you should call `rec_i` inside `rec(n)` like `def rec(n): return rec_i(n,[])`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need without recursion you can check this out:

```py
import numpy as np

def recaman(n):
    series = np.zeros(n)
    series[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if series[i - 1] - i > 0 and series[i - 1] - i not in series:
            series[i] = series[i - 1] - i
        else:
            series[i] = series[i - 1] + i
    return series
```

Answer (score 0):

Using assignment expressions from Python 3.8 (walrus operator) you can generate the Recaman sequence in a single line of code. Unfortunately, it takes O(x^2) time. :(

```
R = [0]; [(R:= R + [R[-1]+x]) if R[-1]-x in R or R[-1] < x else (R := R + [R[-1]-x]) for x in range(1,100)]
```